# How to stream media content from Spring Boot endpoint for javascript client

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot rest service with endpoints defined like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "...", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE) //and octet for videos
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> get(...) {
   //get image as byte array and return
}
```

And the client side in javascript (angular) :

```
var headers = {headers : {..., "Accept":"image/jpeg"}}
var response = $http.get(...);
obj.imageSrc = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + response;
obj.Image = new Image();
obj.Image.src = obj.imageSrc;
```

**What I require**

I thought this endpoint would behave like a regular image file on a file server so that the client can just do a get on it (for reasons outside the scope of this question, it can't actually be a raw image to access with a URL). Apparently this isn't the case - the byte array has to be converted to base64 (is there a way around this, since the array becomes much bigger), which has the effect of rotating the image. I wrongly thought getting an image from an API like this in javascript would be easy :(

Secondly, doing it this way means that javascript has to download the entire array. Is there a way I can define the endpoint to allow for a stream so that javascript can get it in chunks (I imagine both Spring and JS have utility functions that would handle this?)

**The basic underlying question**

How do I implement this properly in Spring so as to be as Javascript friendly as possible? Bearing in mind I want to serve both images (~5MB) and videos (~100MB)

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Perhaps I should be using FileResourceStream as the return type? No idea if this is the "right" way.

Comment: Why do you have to use a data url in your js? If you use the url of your controller directly as src, you don't need the base64 encoding and you can return the "raw" bytes....    EDIT: and you shoud make your controller method directory write to the response output stream and return void..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Don't use a data url. Use the direct url of your controller-method.

2) Write directly to the http-response's output:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dyna.jpg", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public void getImage(HttpServletResponse response) {
    //write byte-array or -stream to the response using
    // response.getOutputStream() 
}
```

P.S. In case you really need the data url there is no otherway around as you do it, since they require the base64  encoding